# CosmosDB How to read replicated data

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, region, azureportal, regions

I'm using CosmosDB and replicating the data globally. (One Write region; multiple Read regions). Using the Portal's Data Explorer, I can see the data in the Write region. How can I query data in the Read regions? I'd like some assurance that it's actually working, and haven't been able to find any info or even an URL for the replicated DBs.

Note: I'm writing to the DB via the CosmosDB "Create or update document" Connector in a Logic App. Given that this is a codeless environment, I'd *prefer* to validate the replication without having to write code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I query data in the Read regions?

If code is possible, we could access from every region your application is deployed, configure the corresponding preferred [regions list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.connectionpolicy.preferredlocations.aspx#P:Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ConnectionPolicy.PreferredLocations) for each region via one of the supported SDKs

The following is the demo code for Azure SQL API CosmosDB. For more information, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/regional-failover).

```
ConnectionPolicy usConnectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy 
{ 
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
    ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp
};

usConnectionPolicy.PreferredLocations.Add(LocationNames.WestUS); //first preference
usConnectionPolicy.PreferredLocations.Add(LocationNames.NorthEurope); //second preference

DocumentClient usClient = new DocumentClient(
    new Uri("https://contosodb.documents.azure.com"),
    "<Fill your Cosmos DB account's AuthorizationKey>",
    usConnectionPolicy);
```

**Update:**

We can enable Automatic Failover from Azure portal. Then we could drag and drop the read regions items to recorder the failover priorties.

[image]

Comment: Tom, Thanks for that sample & approach! It wouldn't be difficult to write a small app to access data from alternate regions. I've updated my question, however, to note that I'd prefer a codeless approach. (I'm not sure that's possible.)

Comment: We also could change the preference location from Azure portal. For more information, please refer to the update answer.

Comment: Tom: Thanks for the updated answer; it does meet the "codeless" goal. I'd point out that since the failovers are presumably transparent to the Read operation, one would need to look at Azure's Service Health page to verify that there are no outages., then assume that the data is being returned by the highest priority region that's available.